# Auto scaling group: how to allow network-in for ec2 from my own ec2? (subnet?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a server (you can think it as a DB) in ec2. Let's call it SERVER-1

I have autoscaling group for web servers. and I want these servers to be able to connect to the SERVER-1

I need to specify ip in the security group of SERVER-1

How can I specify them when I don't know the ip because they will be assigned when created,, they are auto scaling group - controlled ec2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two Security Groups:

- Create a **security group for the app servers** (`App-SG`). Allow inbound access for app usage (eg ports 80, 443). Associate the security group with the Auto Scaling group, which will then associate it with each instance launched by the Auto Scaling group.
- Create a **security group for the database sever** (`DB-SG`). Allow inbound access from `App-SG`. Associate it to SERVER-1.

That is, `DB-SG` should permit inbound connections from `App-SG`. `DB-SG` refers to `App-SG`, which means it will accept inbound connections from any EC2 instance that is associated with `App-SG`. This will continue working as instances are added to, and removed from, the Auto Scaling group.

Comment: should App-SG use SERVER-1's private ip to connect to SERVER-1 ? From one of APP-SG I could connect to SERVER-1 using private ip but public ip isn't working. I'm testing with `telnet ip 5432`

Comment: Always use the Private IP address when communicating within a VPC, otherwise the traffic goes out of the VPC and back in again (and doesn't work with named references in security groups). The security groups should not generally need an IP address specified.